# Can I link my Overwatch account from one PC to another?

Tags: pc, overwatch

I know that you can't link a console account to a PC, but what about PC to PC? I just got a new computer, and I want to move my old account to my new computer, so how do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Overwatch account is tied to your Blizzard account.

As long as you log into the same account on your new computer everything will automatically transfer over.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to link anything - your account is your Blizzard account, you can use this account on any computer with battle.net.